# trying to align horizontally with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I try to create 2 menu bar but I can't align horizontally menu-button since the number of element is not the same.
I tried with max-witdh, flex-basis, flex-grow, flex-shrink property but I can't achieve what I want.

Here you can find a code snippet :

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
   
}
  p, .myCustomButton {
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 2.8em;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0.4rem 0.2rem;
    padding: 0 1em;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .row2 {
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .myCustomButton {
    max-width: 20%;
    flex: 0.1 0.1 auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
</div>

<div class='row row2'>
  <p class='myCustomButton'>test</p>
</div>
```

I would like to have the same size between my custom button and test buttons in every situation (responsive). Which way I can achieve that ? which css property I should look for ? for me it's flex-basis but I don't know how to use it, I have read how it works from mozzila doc, maybe I missed something

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add `align-items:center`  and `display:flex` to `.row p` to align vertically center

Comment: This is not what I want to do.

Comment: Its not very clear what you are looking for, I'm afraid. do you mean that you want the 2 row of buttons evenly spaced or (row1+row2) centered in the container? For example, (using a random px value purely for illustration!) do you mean  e.g. `50px gap | row1 | 50px gap | row2 | 50px gap` ? Or `100px gap | row 1 | small margin | row 2 | 100px gap` ?

Comment: I want all test buttons have the same size every time. Currently, the test button 'customButton' in row2 do not respect the same behaviour as the buttons in row1. (especially for the width)

Comment: You asked about aligning the buttons *vertically* - I think you mean *horizontally* then? The width has nothing to do with the vertical...

Comment: yes, sorry for the mistake. I have edited my thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the last element doesn't fit the size of the other ones it's because of the margins.
Adding an additional `<div>` around the `<p>` and telling the one in `row2` not to grow beyond 20% basis did the trick for me:

```
<div class='row row2'>
   <div>
    <p class='myCustomButton'>test</p>
   </div>
</div>

.row2 > div {
  flex: 0 1 20%;
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.row > div {
  flex: 1 1 20%;
}

p {
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 2.8em;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0.4rem 0.2rem;
  padding: 0 1em;
  flex: 1;
}

.row2 {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.row2 > div {
  flex: 0 1 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
    <div>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
     <div>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='row row2'>
    <div><p class='myCustomButton'>test</p></div>
</div>
```

If possible I would recommend using CSS grids, it's easier that way:

https://codepen.io/sergiofruto/pen/zYqmKYW

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add your Codepen examples as Stack Snippets into the answer itself - you can use the `[<>]` button on the answer toolbar to do this. External links are discouraged here as they can change or break over time, making your answer unhelpful to future users if they can't see the code :)

Comment: I can ensure you that the margin are exactly the same but the content is not the same in my browser.
When I use grid, margin are no longer available (never work with grid). this is a good response but not enought to resolve my question.

Comment: I tried the grid solution and the div solution, do not work in my context.

Comment: finally I achieved that with the grid sample perfectly.